# C++: Best way to use vector in send bytes over tcp/ip

Tags: c++, vector, tcp

I have a problem for transferring big data over tcp/ip. The size of vector of byte to transfer is always about 500000. 
I have 2 solution to deal with this, but I don't know what is the better or having another solution.

For 2 solution, I have 2 class to store data. Each class have 2 methods is:

1. `push(std::vector<BYTE_T& data>);`
2. `vector<BYTE_T >pop();`

`#define BYTE_T unsigned char`

Way 1:Use `vector<BYTE_T>`

```
    class buffDdata1 {
      vector<BYTE_T> listData;
      vector<BYTE_T> listDataTmp;
public:      
     buffDdata1 () {
        listData.reserver(500000);
        listDataTmp.reserver(500000);
     }
void push(vector<BYTE_T>& data) {
     lock();
     listData.insert(listData.end(), data.begin(), data.end());
     unlock();
}

vector<BYTE_T>& pop() {
          lock();
          listDataTmp.clear();
          listDataTmp.swap(listData);
          unlock();
          return listDataTmp;
}
};
```

Way 2: Use `vector` of `vector`

```
class buffData2 {

      vector<vector <BYTE_T> > listData;
      int nCount;
public:
      buffData2() {
           listData.reserver(200000);
      }
      void push(vector <BYTE_T>& data) {
           lock();
           listData.push_back(data);nCount++;
           unlock();
      }
      vector <BYTE_T> pop() {
           vector <BYTE_T> listRet;
           lock();
           for(int i=0; i< nCount; ++i) {
                listRet.insert(listRet.end(), listData[i].begin(), listData[i].end());
           }
           unlock();
           return listRet;
      }
};
```

Comment: You have a vector of every byte?!?!

Comment: Why build the list or the stack at all? Just write the bytes directly. I don't even understand why you have the `vector<BYTE_T>.`

Comment: @EJP the code presents vaguely reasonable way to let the app accumulate data in a thread safe non-blocking way, such that the `push()`ing worker threads don't have to worry about intermingled partial sends, retries and/or blocking.  Not nice code, but it does serve some purpose.

Comment: Tony D Sure but it is accumulating 50,000 bytes per list/stack entry. Surely it is more important to get this stuff written to the network, rather than a fast non-blocking way of accumulating megabytes of pending data to be output? And whatever is writing this stuff to the network is going to have to lock the data structure while it does so. The benefits are illusory.

Comment: @EJP: "Surely it is more important to get this stuff written to the network" - to avoid the intermingling I mentioned while threads send instead of pushing they need to contest and hold a lock for the duration of transmission.  That has major implications for the overall processing - whether it matters is hard to say when we don't know whether the same threads go on to produce many more blocks or stop after one, how CPU intensive / non-connection I/O bound etc. the preparation of the blocks being transmitted is, but there's no basis for concluding "benefits are illusory".

Comment: @TonyD Certainly there is. The writing thread has to synchronize on the data structures, which eliminates the apparent speed of adding to it that appears in this code only if you disregard the actual problem, which remains the I/O. If you just had every thread synchronizing in and writing to the socket directly you would get exactly the same throughout with far less risk.

Comment: @EJP you're ignoring the time those threads need to spend *generating* the data they they want transmitted; reducing the time they're blocked and serialised in transmission means they can spend more time running concurrently, doing data processing.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1 has pushing threads append data while holding the lock (so the push is O(N) in the number of bytes), while Way 2 has O(1) push but more work later for the popping thread (and the lock held throughout).

Which will be better depends on the nature of your work - but it's complicated enough and the significance doubtful enough that you should simply profile both with your actual workloads.

There are other alternatives - for example, particularly if your average push is of reasonable size (e.g. kilobytes or more) - you might use way 2 and return the vector of vectors - letting the popping code send each in turn without spending the time to consolidate them into a larger application buffer.  Your TCP implementation will consolidate them anyway (if you send them fast enough that e.g. the Naggle algorithm doesn't get impatient and send what's available at the time).

Separately, you don't need `nCount` - `vector`s expose their `size()`, and `listData.reserve(200000);` seems really excessive - not that it's likely to matter.

Comment: Thank Tony D for your answer. My problem is data to transfering is continuously and really big. Vector size is always pushed by 50000. So can you help me to structure the data?

Comment: @MaiKy: so - you're sending a lot of data... why's that a problem?  Do you want to produce it more slowly so your program uses less memory?  Do you not think the `pop()`-ping code already sending it as fast as it can?  What "structure" could you possibly want superimposed on blocks of characters queued for transmission down a byte stream?  It's too late to add "structure" in the only sense I can imagine - data to guide deserialisation - that needs to be done before the `push`.  I don't understand your actual, concrete problem.